# Connect to database, got access denied error code 1045

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am learning php now. I got a database information from my supervisor. But I have no idea how to use it. I am trying to access database to create some forms for my php.

all I have: Database Host, Database Name, Database User, Database password.

I was trying to connect to that host by ssh.

```
shell> ssh username@database host
```

Then, I logged into server. And, I tried:

```
shell> mysql -h databasehost -u username -p
```

then, I inputed database password.

I got a Access Denied Error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vincent.ma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have no idea how it works.

How can I use my database?

Comment: Ask your supervisor. That will be doing yourself, your supervisor, and your company a favor. Help to develop a culture of humility and learning!

Comment: `I inputed database password.` I don't think so. It clearly states `using password: NO` Read this - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Comment: So you have database password or ssh password?